# No se guardan de forma correcta datos en una matriz que ingreso a una funcion programa en C

Tags: c++, array, funciones, matrices

Les explico, estoy trabajando en un ejercicio de realizar combinaciones y utilicé un método de binarios, todo esto en C, que va generando todas las posibles combinaciones.

El problema que estoy teniendo es al almacenar la información en la matriz que le entrego a mi función que realiza las combinaciones, solo se guarda la información dentro de la función y cuando lo que retorna lo necesito usar en el main, los valores cambian y a todo le pone cero.

He estado mucho tiempo intentando ver cual es el problema y de verdad no lo entiendo. Si puedierna iluminarme por favor, les dejo mi código.
La funcion `combinatory` es la que realiza las combinaciones y la matriz ingresada, es la que almacenará la información de las combinaciones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct data{
    char* nombre;
    int peso;
    int puntos;
}data;

data *datos;


char* convertToBinario(int number){
    
    char bit[64];
    int dividendo, resto, contador;
    
    dividendo = number;
    contador = 0;
    
    do {
        resto = dividendo % 2;
        bit[contador++] = resto + '0';
        
    }while ( dividendo /= 2 );
    
    bit[contador] = '\0';
    
    static char bitInvertido[64];
    int tamanio;
    
    int i=0;
    while (bit[i] != '\0'){
        if (bit[i] != '\0'){
            tamanio++;
        }
        i++;
        
    }
    
    i = tamanio-1;
    int j = 0;
    while ((i>=0) && (j<tamanio)){
        bitInvertido[j] = bit[i];
        i--;
        j++;
        
    }
    
    bitInvertido[tamanio] = '\0';
    
    
    return bitInvertido;
}


int** combinatory(data* arr, int tamanio, int** soluciones){
    //Sabemos cuantas combinaciones posibles existen usando el metodo de los numeros binarios
    //Sabemos que es 2**n para cualquier entrada.
    int i;
    int numSols = pow(2, tamanio);
    int h;
    int k, elemento;
    for (i=0;i<numSols;i++){
    
        int* saver = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*tamanio); 
        char bit[64];
        
        strcpy(bit, convertToBinario(i));
        
        
        int letters = 0;
        letters = strlen(bit);
        
        while (letters < tamanio){
            char cero[tamanio];
            strcpy(cero,"0");
            strcat(cero, bit);
            strcpy(bit, cero);
            letters++;
        }   
        
        elemento = 0;
        for (k=0;k<letters;k++){
        
            if (strchr("1", bit[k])){   
                saver[k] = 1;
    
            }else{
                saver[k] = 0;
            }       
        }
        
        for (h=0;h<letters;h++){
            elemento=saver[h];
            soluciones[i][h] = elemento;
        }
        
            
        free(saver);
    }   
    return soluciones;
    
}


int main() {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("entrada.in", "r");

    if (f == NULL){
        printf("No se pudo leer el archivo\n");
    }

    char tamanio[50];
    int cantTripulantes, maxPeso;

    fgets(tamanio, 2, f);
    cantTripulantes = atoi(tamanio);

    fgets(tamanio, 5, f);
    maxPeso = atoi(tamanio);
    
    //printf("%d %d", cantTripulantes, maxPeso);
    
    datos = (data*)malloc(sizeof(data)*cantTripulantes);
    
    char name[50], weight[50], points[50];
    int i=0;
    
    while (!feof(f)&&(i<cantTripulantes)){
        
        fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", name, weight, points);
        int N = strlen(name)+1;
        
        datos[i].nombre = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
        
        strcpy(datos[i].nombre, name);
        
        datos[i].peso = atoi(weight);
        
        datos[i].puntos = atoi(points);
        
        i++;
        
    }
    int numSols = pow(2, cantTripulantes);
    
    
    int** soluciones= (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*numSols);
    
    for (i=0;i<numSols;i++){
        soluciones[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cantTripulantes);
    }

    //Se crea la funcion que va a generar las combinaciones y guardarlas en una matriz.
    soluciones = combinatory(datos, cantTripulantes, soluciones);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Hasta donde veo, el retorno del valor es correcto; ¿puede ser que lo que falle sea el cálculo? Es decir, que lo que te devuelva sea el puntero correcto (que además es el mismo pasado por parámetro) pero que *combinaciones* te lo llene de 0. Puedes probar cambiando *combinaciones* para que te rellene el array con un valor fijo. En un pequeño aparte, no necesitas hacer *malloc* y *free* de *saver* en cada iteración, puedes crearlo y liberarlo fuera del bucle principal y reusarlo.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias. Intente hacer eso de ir agregandole un valor fijo a la matriz y pasa lo mismo. Nunca antes me habia pasado algo asi, no entiendo porque pasa.